# Multiple Recursive Makefiles

Tags: c, recursion, makefile

Okay I've tried as much as I can (not knowing a lot about recursive make). So hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on the matter. Here is my listing of the directory structure...

```
SAB->
   -- Makefile
   -- Readme.txt
   -- bin -> Empty
   -- obj -> Empty
   -- src -> Another makefile in here with c sources
      |--> transfer -> Another makefile in here with sources
      |--> prs_socket -> Another makefile in here with sources
```

Below is the make in question and also below that is another makefile. The one from prs_socket directory. Which the latter Makefile doesn't put the -fPIC switch there like it should.

```
# S.A.B. project main makefile

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LDFLAGS=

MAKEFILE = Makefile
TARGETS = build

all: $(TARGETS)

.PHONY: build clean install uninstall
build:
    @echo Building S.A.B.
    cd src && make
    cd src/transfer && make
    cd src/prs_socket && make
    cd src/prs_socket/tests && make

clean:
    @echo Cleaning project...
    @rm -f *~
    cd src/prs_socket && make clean
    cd src/prs_socket/tests && make clean
    cd src/transfer && make clean
    cd src && make clean
    @echo Done cleaning!

install:
    @echo Installing... S.A.B.
    cd src/prs_socket && make install
    cd src/transfer && make install
    cd src && make install
    @echo Done installing!

uninstall:
    @echo Uninstalling... S.A.B.
    cd src/prs_socket && make uninstall
    cd src/transfer && make uninstall
    cd src && make uninstall
    @echo Done uninstalling!
```

Here is the prs_socket directory's makefile that doesn't put -fPIC like it should.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS+=-fPIC
LDFLAGS=-shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libprs_socket.so.1 -lc

TARGET=libprs_socket.so.1.0
BINDIR=../../bin
OBJDIR=../../obj
SRCDIR=../../src
INSTALLDIR?=/opt
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/prs_socket/*.c)
INCLUDES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/prs_socket/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/prs_socket/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.c.o)

all: linux

linux: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJECTS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.c.o: $(SOURCES)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean install uninstall
clean:
    @echo Cleaning up...
    @rm -f *~ $(OBJDIR)/*.c.o $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo Done cleaning!

install:
    @echo Installing...
    @mkdir -p $(INSTALLDIR)/include/prs_socket
    @cp $(SRCDIR)/prs_socket/socket.h $(INSTALLDIR)/include/socket.h
    @cp $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) $(INSTALLDIR)/lib
    @ln -sf $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/$(TARGET) $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/$(TARGET).1
    @ln -sf $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/$(TARGET) $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/libprs_socket.so
    @chmod 0755 $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/$(TARGET)
    @chmod 0755 $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/libprs_socket.so.1
    @chmod 0755 $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/libprs_socket.so
    @echo Install finished!

uninstall:
    @echo Uninstalling...
    @rm -rf $(INSTALLDIR)/include/prs_socket
    @rm -f $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/libprs_socket.so.1
    @rm -f $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/libprs_socket.so
    @rm -f $(INSTALLDIR)/lib/$(TARGET)
    @echo Uninstall finished.
```

Thanks in advance, if more information is needed please let me know.

Update: Here is what displays after running make, removing the @.

```
philip@slackbox:~/debug/SAB$ make
Building S.A.B.
cd src && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/philip/debug/SAB/src'
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o ../obj/socket.c.o ../src/socket.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o ../obj/helper.c.o ../src/helper.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o ../obj/espeech.c.o ../src/espeech.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o ../obj/main.c.o ../src/main.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o ../obj/transfer.c.o ../src/transfer.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  ../obj/socket.c.o ../obj/helper.c.o ../obj/espeech.c.o ../obj/main.c.o ../obj/transfer.c.o -o ../bin/SAB -lespeak
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/philip/debug/SAB/src'
cd src/transfer && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/philip/debug/SAB/src/transfer'
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c main.c -o ../../obj/sab_transfer.c.o
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  ../../obj/sab_transfer.c.o ../../obj/transfer.c.o ../../obj/socket.c.o -o ../../bin/SAB_transfer 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/philip/debug/SAB/src/transfer'
cd src/prs_socket && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/philip/debug/SAB/src/prs_socket'
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libprs_socket.so.1 -lc -o ../../bin/libprs_socket.so.1.0 ../../obj/socket.c.o
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: ../../obj/socket.c.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `create_bind' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../../obj/socket.c.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:22: recipe for target '../../bin/libprs_socket.so.1.0' failed
make[1]: *** [../../bin/libprs_socket.so.1.0] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/philip/debug/SAB/src/prs_socket'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
philip@slackbox:~/debug/SAB$
```

Comment: Are you seeing all the other `CFLAGS` settings from the top makefile, just not the `-fPIC`? I assume you took off the `@` so you could see the command to check the arguments?

Comment: Well I figured out what the only problem was, I wasn't cleaning the object directory after each project build. As soon as I did that, it works perfectly. Consider it solved.

Comment: Whether the object directory is clear or not shouldn't affect the command arguments used once make decides to run that command. Seems odd. Unless in your problem statement you really meant that the entire command was being skipped.

Comment: Nope, what I meant was the directory was wiped (non-existent), make was trying to write to a directory that wasn't there anymore.